# Access and SQL Server: Recordset Update ODBC-error with space characters

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, odbc

I am having a weird error.

My task is to import data from `Oracle 11g` to `MS Access` (Legacy `VBA`-Code with a lot of business logic) which is then shipped to `MS SQL Server` as our new backend via the integrated `ODBC`-Provider.

The VBA-import works fine until I encounter fields with only space-characters in it which causes the following error in the line `rst.Update`:

> run-time error -2147217887(80040e21), ODBC-call failed

The field (Birthplace) is not mandatory, there are many null-entries or entries with spaces inbetween (New York). The error only occurs when there is nothing in the field except spaces.

The spaces are of the form Chr(32) which is equal to normal space on the keyboard which shouldn't be a problem

When working with an Access frontend/backend, there is no problem with the fields, but when saved to the SQL Server backend, the ODBC Error occurs.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Interesting question. If you try to enter only spaces into a table in Access (be it native or linked ODBC), Access will silently replace this with NULL. So it's something Access "doesn't like" (so to speak). I don't have any technical details for that, but you might save yourself some grief by simply doing this replacement yourself during the import.

Comment: Handling the error with a function would be wise since it occured couple of times already. What bothers me is not knowing what the reason is since Access has no problems with it in one configuration (ACC FE/BE) and refuses it in another (ACC FE/SQL BE).